# Background buttons Images in tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I have tableView with array of images. But when I scroll my tableView some images in buttons changes to another. Its happens because I use this line:`button?.tag = indexPath.row`. How to use this line and fix it?

Full code:

```
let array = ["","","","","","",""]
let arrayI = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image4.png","image5.png","image6.png","image7.png"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return array.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)

        let button = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
        button?.tag = indexPath.row

        button?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: arrayI[indexPath.row]), for: .normal)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need that tag? You could create a custom UITableViewCell subclass with that button outlet and set background image for it.

Comment: The way you are practicing is wrong, Please take Custom UITableViewCell class and directly set image.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps to load a tableview with custom cell,

**Step 1:** Create a Custom UITableviewCell class, do design your cell in this class.

**Step 2:** Register that cell for your UITableView like in your view controller's viewDidLoad.

```
self.tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "customTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customTableCell")
```

**Step 3:** Write tableview delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableCell", for: indexPath) as! customTableCell
    cell.button?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: arrayData[indexPath.row]), for: .normal)
    return cell
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to give datasource and delegate connections of tableview to files owner in your XIB.

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Step 3 should be in your  view controller.

Comment: I create UITableviewCell. Add button in cell and `cell.button?.tag = indexPath.row`. And All works. Why I should register like step 2?

Comment: Then for setting background for a UIButton in reusable cell, why you are  using button.tag(is this to identify after click), you stated "images in buttons changes to another. Its happens because I use this line:button?.tag = indexPath.row" which is unrelated.

Comment: Where I should do step 2?